# UIControl not recognizing tap inside table view cell, stopped working from iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application I started, before iOS 14 came out. I stopped with Swift for few months, and now, the emulator is running iOS 14, since then, I have a problem that a UIControl I have inside a tableView cell does not register taps.

This is my TableView (plain, nothing custom or anything):

```
private let tableView: UITableView = {
    let table = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
    table.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    table.backgroundColor = .white
    table.separatorInset.right = table.separatorInset.left
    
    
    return table
}()
```

This is how I try to set the tap gesture:

```
extension TodoListVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: todoCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TodoCell
    
    let todo = todoListViewModel.todos[indexPath.row]
    cell.model = todo
    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    
    
    let checkBox = cell.checkbox
    checkBox.index = indexPath.row
    checkBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onCheckBoxValueChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged) // touchUpInside also does not work.
    
    
    return cell
}

@objc func onCheckBoxValueChange(_ sender: UICheckBox) {
    var todo = todoListViewModel.todos[sender.index]
    todo.isDone = sender.isChecked
    tableView?.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: sender.index, section: 0)], with: .none)
    todoListView.reloadProgress()
}
}
```

The checkbox is a custom UIControl I copied from a tutorial, it worked great before iOS 14, and I can't figure out what's the problem with it now. The file is quite large to add here, but if this is necessary I can provide the code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to your `TodoCell` and add this in your `initializer`:

```
 override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

}
```

It will start working again. If you have not created the cells programatically then you can do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: todoCellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! TodoCell

let todo = todoListViewModel.todos[indexPath.row]
cell.model = todo
cell.selectionStyle = .none
cell.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

let checkBox = cell.checkbox
checkBox.index = indexPath.row
checkBox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onCheckBoxValueChange(_:)), for: .valueChanged) // touchUpInside also does not work.


return cell
}
```

To debug, you can print the value of `contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled` and it will give you the boolean and using that you can see if it is the issue or not. Most probably it will return `false` and the above solution works well for iOS 14 and Xcode 12.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is working again. Would you please share how do you know that? I searched, but didn't find that. Just so I know where to look next time. Thanks!

Comment: I was also stuck just like you, then I started `debugging` and found this as the issue/change. Please mark it as correct answer, so that everyone facing this issue can see that this solution works.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I marked this as the correct answer (had to wait a few minutes before this was possible)

Comment: @Rob Dude you are a genius! Thank you!

Comment: Thank you very much, works as intended. Had the same problem where iOS 14> cell tap wouldn't trigger anything. This solves it.

Comment: @Wamasa Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Also, `isUserInteractionEnabled` for each `subview` in the used `UIControl` must be set to false.

```
subview.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```